# Object doesn`t return expected value

Tags: java, factory-method

I am learning about *factory methods* and I tried to write a class using them.

```
 public enum Animal{  
    DOG(1), CAT(2), PIG(3);  

    private int code;

    public static Animal dog(){  
    return DOG; }  
    public static Animal cat(){  
    return CAT; }    
    public static Animal pig(){  
    return PIG; } 

 public Animal(){  
    switch(this):  
       case DOG: {this.code=1;}  
       case CAT: {this.code=2;}  
       case PIG: {this.code=3;}
 }

 public Animal(int i){  
    if(i==1){return DOG;}
    else if(i==2){return CAT;}  
    else if(i==3){return PIG;}
}

 public int code(){return this.code}
```

Ok, so now the problem is that I create new object for ex. `Animal pet = dog();`
But when I try to ask for the code I get `0`.

```
system.out.print(pet.code());
```

The result is 0.
Is my implementation of the factory methods wrong or is is something else I am not seeing ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: I am sorry if my code is not described as expected. I have cut out all the necessary functions before, I think here are right now only the relevant code parts.

Comment: That code won't compile, so it's missing some important things.

Comment: your switch structure is missing `break;` statements in each case body. Without the `break` statement the switch will fall through after entering one of the cases based on the switch expression. So for example, If the case is DOG it will first assign 1 to code, but because you dont break from the switch after that it will continue to execute the cases below the `DOG` case, leaving you with a final value of 3 for `code`. So add `break;` to atleast the `DOG` and `CAT` cases.

Comment: by the way, in your code you are creating an `enum` not a `class`. You cant instantiate an enum, nor can you use it as a superclass type to declare a variable with. Also this `Animal pet = dog();` doesn't make sense because you forgot to use the new operator for creating a new object. Change Animal to a class and then change your line to `Animal pet = new dog();`

Answer (score 0):

your example has code `Animal pet = dog();` but sample code does not have `dog()` method.

Below that assume that method `dog()` returns `Animal.DOG`.

Please remove parameterless constructor. It is really confusing. You use `this` in constructor, when your object is not fully initialized.

You should have only  one(parametrized) constructor. 
Also, parametrized constructor should not have switch. That constructor should just assing member variable `code` based on value on the parameter.

```
public Animal(int code){  
    this.code=code;
}
```

also, `private int code;` field should be `final`.

If you need more details, please check official documentation (second example with `enum Planet`)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html
It shows how to write and use enums with custom constructor and custom methods.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have two constructors because I want to cover two cases> Once when I create an instance by saying the "name" and once if I know the code.

Comment: if you want to construct enum by name (string) then you need another member variable name of type string and lookup method. if you want to get instance by DOG,CAT, etc then it is not needed since you have insance object at hand.

Argumentless ctor will not help you to lookup anything.

Comment: Some new knowledge for me :) I will improve it

Comment: @TrickerMacedonia official tutorial I linked is also available in form of the book. https://www.amazon.com/Java-Tutorial-Short-Course-Basics-ebook/dp/B00QIUP56U/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1

I also recommend one of java books from https://www.quora.com/Which-is-the-best-book-for-java-for-beginners https://www.journaldev.com/6162/5-best-core-java-books-for-beginners

with any of those you will learn best patterns and practices and become much better programmer.

Comment: @TrickerMacedonia if you find the answer usefull it is good idea to accept/upvote the answer. thanks!